# Detect when tracking pixel is returned from server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Customers use a service where they install a script (javascript) from my server. I have a tracking pixel inserted onto the page via the script that picks up click info.

When the asp.net server intercepts pixel.aspx it inserts the login information from the fake image's querystring into the database and returns pixel.gif...all this works perfectly (see below).

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Web

Public Class HelloWorldModule
Implements IHttpModule
Private pattern As String = "/images/(?<key>.*)\.aspx"
Private logoFile As String = "~/images/pixel.gif"

Public Sub New()
End Sub

Public ReadOnly Property ModuleName() As String
    Get
        Return "HelloWorldModule"
    End Get
End Property

' In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
' events by adding your handlers. 
Public Sub Init(ByVal application As HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init
    AddHandler application.BeginRequest, AddressOf GetImage_BeginRequest
End Sub

Public Sub GetImage_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As System.EventArgs)
    'cast the sender to a HttpApplication object
    Dim application As System.Web.HttpApplication = CType(sender, System.Web.HttpApplication)

    Dim url As String = application.Request.Path 'get the url path
    'create the regex to match for becon images
    Dim r As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    If r.IsMatch(url) Then
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = r.Matches(url)
        If Not (mc Is Nothing) And mc.Count > 0 Then
            Dim key As String = mc(0).Groups("key").Value
            'SaveToDB(key)
        End If

        'now send the image to the client
        application.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"
        application.Response.WriteFile(application.Request.MapPath(logoFile))
        application.Response.End()
    End If
End Sub 'GetImage_BeginRequest
```

If a client that is running this script has an expired account I want to return an error.gif in the response (instead of pixel.gif) and then I need to detect the error.gif src so I can notifiy the client that the service has expired.

I have tried the following, but it returns the original src of the image. How do I detect the updated src of the image?

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

```
testImage("images/pixel.aspx?login=123&country=canada", function (url, result) { if (result === 'success') { console.log(url) } }, 10000);

     function testImage(url, callback, timeout) {
        timeout = timeout || 5000;
        var timedOut = false, timer;
        var img = new Image();
        img.onerror = img.onabort = function () {
            if (!timedOut) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                callback(url, "error");
            }
        };
        img.onload = function () {
            if (!timedOut) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                callback(url, "success");
                console.log(checkURL(url))
            }
        };
        img.src = url;
        document.body.appendChild(img);

        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            timedOut = true;
            callback(url, "timeout");
        }, timeout);
    }

 function checkURL(url) {
        return (url.match(/\.(jpeg|jpg|gif|png)$/) != null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I never found something that could identify the image src, due the server sending the pixel.gif before the page rendered so no script could ever detect a src change.  I put the logic on the server so that when the customer account expired, I now display a message on the requesting web page of the account expiry...

```
' In the Init function, register for HttpApplication 
' events by adding your handlers. 
Public Sub Init(ByVal application As HttpApplication) Implements IHttpModule.Init
    If acct_expired = False Then
        AddHandler application.BeginRequest, AddressOf GetImage_BeginRequest
    Else
        AddHandler application.BeginRequest, AddressOf Application_BeginRequest ' GetImage_BeginRequest
    End If

End Sub

Public Sub GetImage_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As System.EventArgs)
    'cast the sender to a HttpApplication object
    Dim application As System.Web.HttpApplication = CType(sender, System.Web.HttpApplication)

    Dim url As String = application.Request.Path 'get the url path
    'create the regex to match for becon images
    Dim r As New Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    If r.IsMatch(url) Then
        Dim mc As MatchCollection = r.Matches(url)
        If Not (mc Is Nothing) And mc.Count > 0 Then
            Dim key As String = mc(0).Groups("key").Value
            'SaveToDB(key)
        End If

        'now send the image to the client
        application.Response.ContentType = "image/gif"
        application.Response.WriteFile(application.Request.MapPath(logoFile))
        application.Response.End()

    End If
End Sub 'GetImage_BeginRequest

Private Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal source As Object, _
         ByVal e As EventArgs)
    ' Create HttpApplication and HttpContext objects to access 
    ' request and response properties. 
    Dim application As HttpApplication = DirectCast(source, HttpApplication)
    Dim context As HttpContext = application.Context
    Dim filePath As String = context.Request.FilePath
    Dim fileExtension As String = VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(filePath)
    context.Response.Write("<hr><h1><font color=red>Your account has expired. Upgrade Today!</font></h1>")
End Sub
```